# Android XML Layout overlapping

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a ratingBar and a twoTabList that I want to sit so that the ratingBar is above the twoTabList, and they both take up the whole screen horizontally. However whenever I try and place one of them it cuts the other out of the screen.

Here's my code right now for the .xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:rating="3"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_weight="144" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/tabTwoList"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="444dp"
    android:layout_weight="116.25">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! This made the design output of android studio show it looking how i want it, but when i run the emulator it shows the rating bar on top, and then the twoTabList along the entire length vertically, and cut in about half horizontally. any ideas?

Comment: Please draw the design you want . I will help.